# Udpclient polling UDP multicast address

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, multicast, udpclient

I want to check if data is avaiable on the UDP multicast address, the only mechanism I found was the `Poll` method.

Setup:

```
client = new UdpClient(localEp);
client.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastAddr, localIpAddress);
client.Connect(multicastAddr, receiveport);
```

Polling:

```
if (!client.Client.Poll(100, SelectMode.SelectRead))
```

The client is connected (I checked) but never returns true.
In wireshark I can see the udp datagrams are sent correctly.

Suggestions for fixes?

Edit:

IPEndpoint localEp = local ipv4 unicast address, port for multicast udps
receiveport = port for receiving multicasts 
multicastaddr = IPAddress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting UDP socket means restricting datagram source address and port to the specified pair when receiving, and setting default destination address and port when sending.

Remove call to [`Connect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx13cwba.aspx).

#### Edit 0:

You need to bind to the multicast address, not the local IP. Either remove `localEp` from the constructor, or replace it with pair of the multicast group/port. See [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekd1t784.aspx) on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.joinmulticastgroup%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

And you are wrong, you can [`Receive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive.aspx) just one datagram.

Comment: i already tried removing connect, or join one by one. But still the poll method always returns false

Comment: How about just `Receive`-ing? Also what are the values in `localEp`, `multicastAddr`, `localIpAddress`, and `receivePort`?

Comment: The thing is, microsoft design for c# sockets. If you start to receive, you can not stop receiving without getting a socketexception. And so i tried to poll to look if data is present before start the receiving process.

Comment: "And you are wrong, you can Receive() just one datagram." I never said anything else!

Comment: Got the code working, seems like the client.Client.Connected is always false but its not needed for the poll method.